# Is it possible to write parquet statistics with pyarrow?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

This option exists in Spark, and I saw that pyarrow's `write_table()` accepts **kwargs, but following up the `.pyx`, I couldn't trace it to stuff like min/max.

Is this supported, and if so, how is it achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyarrow` already writes the min/max statistics for Parquet files by default. There is no option for that in `pyarrow` as the underlying `parquet-cpp` library writes them always. At the time of writing, only min and max are written. The other statistics can neither be provided nor are computed on-the-fly with `parquet-cpp`. When you require them, you should open an issue in [(Py)Arrow's issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARROW) and considering contributing the the missing code for that.